# Point spread function (PSF) expressed as a convolution and a sum

Tags: convolution, image-processing

The Wikipedia article on the Point Spread Function ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function)) discusses how an imaging system can be conceptually described using linear system theory.  A convolution of the PSF with the image in the spatial domain is equivalent to a multiplication in the Fourier domain.

Given $m \times n$ matrices $\bf{A}$ and $\bf{B}$, and assuming that $\bf{A}$ is an image and $\bf{B}$ is another matrix, the addition of the two matrices in the spatial domain is:

$\bf{A} + \bf{B} = \bf{C}$

However, can this addition be expressed as a convolution in the spatial domain?  Could I re-write the addition equation as a convolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolution is used to describe not only linear, but also shift-invariant system.

For $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C}$, it's not even a linear system unless $\mathbf{B}=0$ (I assume $\mathbf{A}$ is the input, $\mathbf{C}$ is the output).

Comment: OK, thanks for pushing me in the right direction.  Yes, $\bf{A}$ is the input and $\bf{C}$ is the output.  So what you are saying is that it is not possible to express the sum of matrices as a convolution?

Comment: ＠Nicholas Kinar Yes, I think so.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this now.